# What is an emphatic particle?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-も, sentence-final-particles

The explanation I have found says that it is a particle on the end of the sentence. However, in the book I am reading (*An Integrated Approach to Intermediate Japanese*) it is stated that も is an emphatic particle, the same with さえ.

> An emphatic particle which expresses the idea of "even" in non-conditional clauses (or sentences) or the idea of "only" in conditional clauses.
>
> ● **Notes**
>
> 1. も as an emphatic marker is an extended use of も1. The following examples show the transition of meaning from the original idea "also" to the emphatic use "even"
>
>    a. グレーさんは非常に難しい漢字も読める。
>      *Literally:* Mr. Gray can read very difficult kanji, too. (Mr. Gray can read *even* very difficult kanji.)

Also, I have seen comments saying that something is more emphatic than something else, or emphatic statement.

It has been bothering me for a while already and I would like to see an explanation if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your confusion comes from the fact that there is more than one way to use particles for an emphatic effect.

#### Sentence final particles

Sentence final particles よ, ぞ, ぜ, わ and others are [sometimes called](https://www.lingualift.com/blog/japanese-emphatic-particles/) *emphatic particles*. They are added to the end of a sentence for an emphatic effect — for example, conveying that you feel strongly about something.

Sentence final particles usually emphasize the statement of the **whole sentence**.

There are many such particles, although よ is particularly common and versatile. Choosing between such particles will depend on nuance, register, gender, etc. and there are many questions about these:

- [In what situations can you use ぞ as a sentence ender](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/617/1628)
- [ぜ at the end of sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12072/1628)
- [Difference between ぞ and ぜ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30192/1628)
- [When women use わ at the end of a sentence, is it different from よ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2886/1628)
- [わ usage at the end of sentences](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/244/1628)
- [how could a sentence end with (noun + "よ"?)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12986/1628)

Also see the tag [sentence-final-particles](/questions/tagged/sentence-final-particles) or the individual tags [particle-よ](/questions/tagged/particle-%e3%82%88), [particle-わ](/questions/tagged/particle-%e3%82%8f), etc.

---

#### Particle も

The particle も can be used to emphasize a **particular word** within a sentence.

For the emphatic use of も the [プログレッシブ和英中辞典 lists following example sentences](https://kotobank.jp/jeword/%E3%82%82)

> **3** 〔さえ〕
>
> - 猿も木から落ちる
>     *Even* monkeys fall from trees occasionally.／*Even* an expert makes mistakes.／(*Even*) Homer sometimes nods.
> - 彼はありがとうも言わずにそれを取った
>     He took it without *so much as* saying thank you.
>
> ---
>
> **5** 〔強調〕
>
> - この品物は1万円もした
>     This (article) cost *no less than* [*all of*] 10,000 yen.
> - 彼はそれを完成するのに10年もかかった
>     It took him ten long years to complete it.
> - 10人もの人が皆同じ間違いをした
>     *All* ten people made the same mistake.
> - この村の者は一人も知らない
>     I don't know a single one of the villagers.
> - 冗談もいいところだ
>     You are carrying your joke too far.
> - こうも暑いとぐったりしてしまう
>     When it's as hot as this, I feel listless.
> - そんなことをするとは非常識もはなはだしい
>     It was simply too thoughtless of him to do such a thing.
> - 今まで黙っているなんて君も君だよ
>     Why didn't you let me know earlier? I'm surprised at you.／How could you not have told me?
> - 歌いも歌ったり，その数は50曲に及んだ
>     We sang and sang until we had finished fifty songs.
> - 3時間も待った
>     I waited for a *good* three hours.

---

#### Particle さえ

Similarly, the particle さえ can be used for an emphatic effect. Again, the [プログレッシブ和英中辞典 lists the following example sentences](https://kotobank.jp/jeword/%E3%81%95%E3%81%88)

> **1** 〔さらに〕
>
> - 雨さえ降ってきた
>     *On top of that* [*everything*], it began to rain.
>
> ---
>
> **2** 〔…ですら〕even
>
> - 彼さえ知らないのだからだれも知らないだろう
>     If *even* he doesn't know, then nobody does.
> - ABCさえ書けない
>     He can't *even* write the alphabet.／He cannot *so much as* write the alphabet.
> - 1滴の水さえない
>     There is not a drop of water (to be had [found]).
> - 彼は兄弟にさえ裏切られた
>     He was betrayed *even* by his own brothers.
>
> ---
>
> **3** 〔そのことだけで十分〕
>
> - もっと勉強しさえすれば試験に合格できたのに
>     If *only* you had studied harder, you could have passed the examination.
>     これさえあれば十分だ
>     This is all I need.

Also see

- [さえ how to use it](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33409/1628)

---

#### Contrastive particle は

The particle は can also be used for contrast/emphasis. See for example

- [What's the difference between wa (は) and ga (が)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/22/1628)

---

#### Combining "emphatic particles"

Of course there is no reason you cannot combine sentence final particles and emphatic も or さえ — just pick any of the above example sentences and add an "emphatic" sentence final particle.

---

#### Other expressions used for emphasis

On top of that, there are other words or expressions used for emphasis. For example

- [Usage of なんて and なんか as emphasis](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/421/1628)
- [Usage of nan desu?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14565/1628)

Comment: Thank you very much, I assume that こそ is also an emphatic particle, right?

Comment: In the 10 people example sentence, is the emphasis on "all" or on "ten people"? (As in "Of the *ten* people [who tried this], all made the same mistake!")

Comment: @muru The italics is only indicating what part of the English sentence roughly corresponds to the も in the Japanese sentence. I think it could also have said "*As much as* ten people made the same mistake".